# Testing async methods with PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I tried using a sleep and try approach. But it fails sometimes. What is the standard? Can't find anything obvious around. Thanks.

```
function foo($callback)
{
    $bar->asyncCall($callback);
}

function testFoo()
{
    $semaphore = 1;
    foo(function() {
        $semaphore = 0;
    });
    sleep(5) until $semaphore == 0;
}
```

With this approach testFoo() sometimes never returns. I suspect a deadlock somewhere.

Comment: PHP doesn't support built-in async (you could actually use the PECL Thread tho).

What you are actually doing here is just passing an anonymous function. you should provide more details about the `asyncCall` and maybe return a response that you could verify it has been called.

Answer (score 2):

The way php scopes variables, you are not changing the same `$semaphore` variable in your test. You are creating a new variable in the anonymous method you pass to `foo(...)`.

You would need to mark the var with the `use` keyword.

```
function testFoo()
{
    $semaphore = 1;
    foo(function() use ($semaphore) {
        $semaphore = 0;
    });
    $this->assertEquals(0, $semaphore);
}
```

No need for the sleep then since this is not asynchronous from what we can see from here. More info on the `$bar->asynCall()` would be needed.
See more on variable scope here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php